# MySQL Join 4 tables shows wrong sum

Tags: mysql

I have rewriten my request. Sorry fot not being specific. You can find the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1cbf1/2

I want to output:

```
# invoice 1 - customer 1, items total:500, quantity:5, paid 250
# invoice 2 - customer 1, items total: 360, quantity:4, paid 300
# invoice 3 - customer 2, items total - 650, quantity: 5, paid 300
# invoice 4 - customer 3, items total - 210, quantity: 2, paid 110
# invoice 5 - customer 3, items total - 0, quantity: 0, paid 0
```

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    invoices.invoice_id,
    customers.last_name,
    COUNT(items.item_invoice_id) as quantity,
    SUM(payments.payment_amount) as total_paid,
    SUM(items.item_price) as subtotal

FROM `invoices` 
LEFT JOIN payments
     ON payments.invoice_id = invoices.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN customers
      ON customers.id = invoices.invoice_customer_id

LEFT JOIN items
       ON items.item_invoice_id = invoices.invoice_id

GROUP BY invoices.invoice_id
```

Comment: Please can you add into the question an example of your working with the help of http://rextester.com or http://sqlfiddle.com? Also, please provide a brief description of the output values you'd like to see.

Comment: _something went wrong_ -- Noone can help you if you don't specify what went wrong, and how it differs from your expectation, e.g. _I typed `LEFT JOIN,INNER JOIN` on the screen, and I expected to win a million dollars!_

Comment: I have updated the request.